# What is the preferred way to hold a file over multiple requests in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am building a wizard and the first step of this wizard is to let the user select a file. In the following steps I need this file to display some data from it and as a final step I have to import some content of the selected file.

How can i preserve this file along the steps?

I can save the file on the server in a temp dir (and make sure it is linked to the user's session, so that no other import session will intervene).
I can save the file in the session state (Viewbag maybe?)
What would you do?

Edit:

The size can vary from 100kb - 10mb

Answer (score 3):

You could use Sessions here but that has a few downsides. The oft-quoted one is the default configuration (in process) is fast but the session dies if the app pool gets restarted. Code-wise this means you typically need to check if your session has not died so you can handle it gracefully. This is fairly easy to do but it is some overhead.

The bigger downside there is the fact that the browser shares a session between all tabs so if someone does some normal modern browser stuff you can get massive confusion or at least UI weirdness. A good example of someone doing something like this would be united airlines -- you can only look at one of your flights at once due to session contention.

The approach I would take here is to have them upload the file, stash it in an appropriate place, generate an ID for it and then keep that in the wizard. When they complete it you can pick up the file at the end. If they start 2 at once it is easy to handle. Stay stateless.

Answer (score 0):

The last MVC app I designed I had to hold onto a file through multiple pages before it was 'saved' (as at any point the user could cancel).  I stuck it in Session and all has worked well since.  That said, this feature doesn't get much use (10s of users at once) so I do not have data on how it scales.

While the web is stateless and MVC design lends itself to being as stateless as possible, the only way to make this bit stateless was to have the user send the file with every request that needs it, and that seems bad from a UX side (as well as having to handle scenarios like different files being passed).

Answer (score 0):

In general, holding a file open between user requests is not a good idea. There are several problems:

- The session can time out, leaving the file in limbo. In a busy system, this can lead to file handles running out.
- Many "enterprise" quality web containers serialize your session to a database when they are busy. You don't say what language you are using, but the Java File class is stateful and not Serializable, so you have a problem.
- In a web farm environment, your next request may not be handled by the same server, so the file would have to be on a drive shared across the farm.
- If you are unlucky, several users may want to access the same file concurrently, giving you some difficult synchronisation problems.

So what are the options:

- If the file is small, you may be able to store the data in the session and write it out only on the final submit. But a 10MB file is a bit big for this option.
- Rather than a file, you could persist the data to a database. Record locking, transactions etc are bread and butter features of databases, so a lot of the synchronisation problems just go away.
- There are platform-independent ways of locking a file, but these are a bit arcane. One approach is to use a second "lock" file that contains nothing but the process ID of the file "owner". This gets tricky with web clients, as generally the web container will use a thread pool to service requests.
- If you know you are always going to deploy on the same platform, most OS's provide platform specific semaphores and the like. You might find a library for your language that supports these.

Personally I would go for using a database...

Answer (score 0):

Use a caching mechanism that is independent of the stateless queries run by the user. Much in the same way database connections are pooled - ie you never open a new DB connection apart from the first time, every subsequent 'open' really fetches a previously used connection from a cache inside the DB client driver.

You need to determine a method for handling the file's lifetime, maybe closing it after a minute or so of inactivity but it allows you to treat each access of the file as an entirely new operation from each request and have it perform acceptably.

That said, the OS already performs an amount of file caching so the system may perform very well if you repeatedly re-open the same file within a short amount of time (ie before it exits the OS cache) without having to bother doing anything.